# Unable to crawling next page in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Shows results of first page and i want results from all the pages and it should crawl like 2nd page then 3rd page

```
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    base_url = 'https://www.yell.com'
    start_urls = ['https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?scrambleSeed=770796459&keywords=hospitals&location=united+kingdom']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_data = response.css('div.row.businessCapsule--mainRow')
        for data in all_data:
            title = data.css('.text-h2::text').extract()
            business_url = data.css('a.businessCapsule--title::attr(href)').get()
            final_url = self.base_url + business_url

            yield response.follow(final_url, self.parse)
            avg_rating = response.css('span.starRating--average::text').get()
            items = {
                'Title': title ,
                'Title Url' : final_url,
                'Average Rating': avg_rating
            }
            yield items
        pass

        next_page = response.urljoin(response.css('a.pagination--next::attr(href)').extract_first())
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
class YellSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yell'
    base_url = 'https://www.yell.com{}'
    start_urls = ['https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?scrambleSeed=770796459&keywords=hospitals&location=united+kingdom']

    def parse(self, response):
        for data in response.css('div.row.businessCapsule--mainRow'):
            title = data.css('.text-h2::text').get()
            business_url = data.css('a.businessCapsule--title::attr(href)').get()
            final_url = self.base_url.format(business_url)
            avg_rating = response.css('span.starRating--average::text').get()
            yield {
                'Title': title ,
                'Title Url' : final_url,
                'Average Rating': avg_rating
            }

        next_page = response.css('a.pagination--next::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```